# Python PyQt Pyside - setNameFilters in QFileDialog does not work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qfiledialog

(Windows 7 64 Bit, PyCharm 3.4.1 Pro, Python 3.4.0, PySide 1.2.2)

I want to make a file dialog with filters and preselect one filter.

If i use the static method, it works, i can use filters and preselect one filter.

```
dir = self.sourceDir
filters = "Text files (*.txt);;Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"
selected_filter = "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"
fileObj = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, " File dialog ", dir, filters, selected_filter)
```

If i use an object it does not work, my filters are not there.

```
file_dialog = QFileDialog(self)
file_dialog.setNameFilters("Text files (*.txt);;Images (*.png *.jpg)")
file_dialog.selectNameFilter("Images (*.png *.jpg)")
file_dialog.getOpenFileName()
```

Why does this not work?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `QFileDialog` works.

The functions `getOpenFileName`, `getSaveFileName`, etc are *static*. They create an *internal* file-dialog object, and the arguments to the function are used to set properties on it.

But when you use the `QFileDialog` constructor, it creates an *external* instance, and so setting properties on it have no effect on the *internal* file-dialog object created by the static functions.

What you have to do instead, is show the external instance you created:

```
file_dialog = QFileDialog(self)
# the name filters must be a list
file_dialog.setNameFilters(["Text files (*.txt)", "Images (*.png *.jpg)"])
file_dialog.selectNameFilter("Images (*.png *.jpg)")
# show the dialog
file_dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: "...you will always get the built-in Qt file-dialog instead." Hm. On Windows (see for example the images in the question) both dialogs look remarkably the same. I wonder how to get the non-native file dialog and how to recognize it?

Comment: @Trilarion. It's possible things may have changed since I answered this. Try with: `dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)`. (PS: I've now removed that part of the answer because it's not really rlelevant to the question).

Comment: Yep, that works. Looks like on Windows and Qt5 the native dialog is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Global solution is here. You can get directory, filename and file extension. You can use that:

```
d = Dialog(self)
        d.filters = ['A dosyaları (*.aaa)', 'B Dosyaları (*.bbb)', 'C Dosyaları (*.ccc)', 'Tüm Dosyalar (*.*)']
        d.default_filter_index = 3
        d.exec()
        print(d.filename)
        print(d.path)
```

and class is here!

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QDialog
import os


class Dialog():

    def __init__(self, mainform):
        self.__mainform = mainform
        self.__dialog = QFileDialog()
        self.__directory = ''
        self.__filename = ['', '', '']
        self.__filters = []
        self.__default_filter_index = 0
        self.__path = ''

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.__path

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.__filename

    @property
    def directory(self):
        return self.__directory

    @directory.setter
    def directory(self, value):
        self.__directory = value

    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self.__filters

    @filters.setter
    def filters(self, value):
        self.__filters = value

    @property
    def default_filter_index(self):
        return self.__default_filter_index

    @default_filter_index.setter
    def default_filter_index(self, value):
        self.__default_filter_index = value

    def exec(self, load =True):
        self.__dialog.setNameFilters(self.__filters)
        self.__dialog.selectNameFilter(self.__filters[self.__default_filter_index])
        self.__dialog.setDirectory(self.__directory)
        if load == True:
            self.__dialog.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Accept, 'Aç')
            self.__dialog.setWindowTitle('Aç')
        else:
            self.__dialog.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Accept, 'Kaydet')
            self.__dialog.setWindowTitle('Kaydet')
        if self.__dialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
            self.__path = self.__dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
            fn = os.path.split(self.__path)
            ex = os.path.splitext(self.__path)[1]
            self.__filename = [fn[0], fn[1], ex[1:len(ex)]]
```